# Deal with cycle in R

Tags: r, loops, cycle

I have data as follows:

```
Schedule<-data.frame("Task"=c("A","B","C","D"),"CycleTask"=c(100,150,120,30))
FDate<-data.frame("Date"=seq(1:6),"Cycle"=c(90,100,130,150,170,200))
  Task TaskCycle
1    A       100
2    B       150
3    C       120
4    D        30
  Date Cycle
1    1    90
2    2   100
3    3   130
4    4   150
5    5   170
6    6   200
```

Each task has one required cycle and repeat over time. If the Task is done, it will be counted again as a loop. For example: Task D repeat every 30 cycles
I want to find the date that need to do the Task. Like this

```
  Date Cycle Task
1    1    90    D
2    2   100    A
3    3   130    C,D
4    4   150    B
5    5   170    D
6    6   200  A,D
```

How can I use loop function to deal with this cycle?

Comment: I dont understand your desired output: why is 200 together with A and D 170 is `NA`

Comment: Sorry, my typo. The cycle on 2nd date is 100, not 110
When the task is done, the cycle has to be counted again, that's why the 5th date there is no Task to be done

Comment: that does not answer my question

Comment: @Cettt when the Task A is done, the cycle is 100, therefore it is done again when cycle>= 100+100, and it match cycle of 6th day . Task D is done last time when cycle is 150, it is done again when cycle is 150+30 (1st table) =180, so it need to be done when cycle >=180, so it need to be done on 6th day

Comment: @Cettt Ah yeah, sorry. It should done Task D when cycle is 170. I corrected it

Comment: Hi, please check your examples before posting them: this was already two errors out of six examples. Still it seems strange to me. Can you explain the rule with a mathematical formula or some sort of pseudo algorithm?

Comment: @Cettt I checked the example again. It should correct now.
The result should be based on the 1st table and CycleTask. Like Task A need to be done when the cycle is more than 100, 200, 300, 400 and so on
Task B need to be done when the cycle is more than 150, 300, 450 and so on. Similar to the rest. Do you clear this part?

Comment: Your `Cycle`'s sample data set does not match the `Cycle`'s in your output. Why are they different?

Comment: @avid_useR the `sample` is like a requirement for each Task. The output is like the real cycle and it increases over time but there is no rule. The result I want is how can I extract the Task name base on the required `Cycle` and real `Cycle`

Comment: I understand that, so `TaskCycle` in `Schedule` is your required cycle, and `Cycle` in `FDate` is the real cycle, correct? My question is why does the `Cycle` variable in your last example different from the `Cycle` in `FDate` that you have provided?

Comment: @avid_useR I typed wrong number. I corrected it

Comment: Please check thoroughly.. They are still different.

Comment: @avid_useR Now it should be correct